# Converting a void function that returns Console.WriteLine into a string function?

Tags: c#

I had some recursive problems to solve (and after some struggle I ended up victorious)
I made the functions (that calculates the result for them)  void and after every iteration of the recursive function I called "Console.WriteLine()" to print the line and after I continued with the recursion until a certain condition was met afterwards I called the calculation function into the Main function. Now I want to try to convert them into strings  and make them cleaner and then call the function inside Main with Console.WriteLine(). For example the following code.

```
public static void TowerOfHanoi(int n, char firstRod, char secondRod, char thirdRod)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    TowerOfHanoi(n - 1, firstRod, thirdRod, secondRod);
    Console.WriteLine("From " + firstRod + " to " + secondRod);
    TowerOfHanoi(n - 1, thirdRod, secondRod, firstRod);
}
```

This is for the Tower of Hanoi problem where I have to move a whole stack of discs from a certain rod to another(in my problem from A to B)   using using an intermediary rod C.
The rules:  I can't have a disc larger on top of a smaller one, so every move I make has to keep the smaller discs above the bigger ones.

I tried to change the function from void to string and add a new empty string in there for example:

string result = "";  and instead of the Console.WriteLine  I tried using result+= "From " + firstRod + " to " + secondRod + "\n"; and afterwards call the function into Main using Console.WriteLine. => Here I hit  wall.
This is my failed attempt to convert it:  If I enter  2 as input it should return:

From A to C
From A to B
From C to B.

but with my failed attempt it returns only From A to B.  I know that I should have a variable where I should add all the results after each recursion, but I can't seem to figure it out

```
public static string TowerOfHanoi(int n, char firstRod, char secondRod, char thirdRod)
{
        if (n == 0)
        {
            return "";
        }

        TowerOfHanoi(n - 1, firstRod, thirdRod, secondRod);
        TowerOfHanoi(n - 1, thirdRod, secondRod, firstRod);

        return "From " + firstRod + " to " + secondRod + "\n";
    }
```

Do you have any suggestions on how can I get around this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71209728/converting-a-void-function-that-returns-console-writeline-into-a-string-function    this doesn't help me at all. I can add after the recursion another "return result" and then the code displays an empty string. n== 0 in the void function tells the recursion to stop because there are no moves left to be done.

Comment: You might consider that the recursive calls to your method return values, and they are being ignored.

Comment: I edited my post now, thank you for the suggestion. So the void function which I'm trying to convert into a string function returns  for an input of 2 (which represents the number of discs to be moved) I have to print the following output. "From A to C, From A to B From C to A.  This is for moving all discs from Rod A to Rod B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your updated code significantly changes the logic of the original code in two ways:

1. The "from ... to" result is now *after both* of the recursive calls, whereas previously it was *between* the two recursive calls.
2. The result from those recursive calls is *entirely ignored*.  If a method returns a result, and you want that result, you have to capture it in some way.

For example:

```
var result = string.Empty;
if (n == 0)
{
    return result;
}

result += TowerOfHanoi(n - 1, firstRod, thirdRod, secondRod);
result += "From " + firstRod + " to " + secondRod + "\n";
result += TowerOfHanoi(n - 1, thirdRod, secondRod, firstRod);

return result;
```

You can then start to improve upon the functionality a little bit by using a `StringBuilder` instead of appending strings:

```
if (n == 0)
{
    return string.Empty;
}

var result = new StringBuilder();
result.Append(TowerOfHanoi(n - 1, firstRod, thirdRod, secondRod));
result.Append("From " + firstRod + " to " + secondRod + "\n");
result.Append(TowerOfHanoi(n - 1, thirdRod, secondRod, firstRod));

return result.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you David. I know feel bad for asking this question here, That was pretty straight forward. Thank you a lot!